# Goutte / Symfony DOM Crawler download file from form

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler, screen-scraping, goutte, domcrawler

There is a form in the remote page, which, after submitted, automatically download specific file to your computer. How could I grab that file and store it on server using Goutte or native Symfony DOM Crawler?

Currently I have this code:

```
    $client = new Client();
    $client->setHeader('user-agent', "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36");

    $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'ADDRESS');
    $form = $crawler->selectButton('Get Results')->form();
    $crawler = $client->submit($form);
```

If Goutte does not allow to do this, which technology would?

Comment: I had to simply use $client -> getResponse() -> getContent(); SOLVED!

Comment: Hi can you update your code with the change you have made so it is clear how to do it correctly, i'm having similar problem... Thanks